# Replacing RAM chipsets

Tags: memory, ddr3, replacement

Dears,

I have a laptop with **`4GB of RAM`**. I'm looking to upgrade to **`8GB of RAM`**.
The problem is, the current RAM is **`PC3-8500F`** and I can't find it in the local market.
All I have found is the **`PC3-8500`** and **`PC3-8500S`**..
I'm afraid if I buy any of these won't work.

Has anyone replaced a **`PC3-8500F`** with a **`PC3-8500`** or **`PC3-8500S`**?

EDIT:

Motherboard Model: NSKAA
Motherboard Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
Chipset: Intel Havendal/Clarkdale Host Bridge rev. 02
Southbridge: Intel HM55 rev. 05

Comment: you should check your motherboard manual first. once i tried to replace 1 GB with 2 GB it didn't work. the reason was the notebook has a limit of 1 GB max (over all slots)

Comment: You can always buy faster RAM. // Are you absolutely certain it is fully buffered RAM?

Comment: Give it a look to [this question](https://superuser.com/a/129652/257269) and [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Modules). BTW [edit] your post adding the motherboard model. From the manual and manufacturer's page, you should be able to figure out which chip is compatible or not.

Comment: @alecxs I checked, the device can take up to 8GB

Comment: @DanielB That is what I saw written on the chipset and from CPU-Z

Comment: @Hastur I saw this question before I ask, but I'm not sure if I can apply a module other than the one I have

Comment: @Hastur I've added the model details

Comment: Look, since what you (we) lack of is the info about `PC3-8500S` with the final **S**, you can google the images searching for `PC3-8500S`, then you can read the part number of some chips, then search their datasheet. Finally you can collect the necessary information and be sure of the compatibility with your motherboard model. Good luck. BTW you can always contact the seller and ask for it.

Comment: @DavidPostill it is not a question about hardware shopping recommendations, but about compatibility between PC3-8500F with a PC3-8500 or PC3-8500S on a Toshiba motherboard NSKAA. It asks if someone already tried or knows the compatibility and differences.

Comment: "The problem is, the current RAM is PC3-8500F and I can't find it in the local market.". That is a shopping question. Go to https://www.crucial.com. It will scan your PC and tell you what is compatible.

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry for late answering. I disagree (`:-)`): 1) This means I'm not looking for someone to tell me to buy the exact same model. I may find other ones, not all fully documented, I do not know the hardware specifications for the PC3-8500S and I am asking if someone knows it.   2) from crucial, I'm on Linux, it allows only to download a `file.exe` for windows. 3) [long list](https://www.crucial.com/company/scanner-terms-and-conditions) of obscure privacy concessions (I should seek and follow many laws of another country)...
Is an hardware question off-topic?